# How do I correctly interpolate variables in Ansible var files through a for loop in Jinja2

Tags: ansible

Ansible Vars file to be interpolated after being run against jinja2, but leaving literal string in the vars file

I have a vars file in Ansible that I'm using to interpolate as a applications.yml file. I want the elb.host variable to be set in the applications.yml as the ELB address, however, jinja2 is not interpolating and it's just setting the value as the literal string
"{{ elb_name }}"

Is there a way I can set up an Ansible task to interpolate elb_name within the var file during the for loop that is iterating through service_ext_props?

```
services (var file). The elb_name is a var that is defined in a separate var file already

service_ext_props:
  elb.host: "{{ elb_name }}"

I also have a services.yml.j2 file that iterates through:

{% for key, value in service_ext_props.iteritems() %}
{{ key }}: *{{ value }}*
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your question is horrifically confusing; can you show an example of what output you would expect, and clean up your question to show what -- exactly -- is the input you are providing?